# T-SQL - Insert trigger; IF EXISTS not evaluating as intended

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

Not sure what I'm missing. When I debug and step through the `INSERT` query I've included below, I see that `'%a%'` is the value of `@Answer`, and 103 is the value for `@ItemId`.

`IF EXISTS` is always evaluating to false when I insert the values shown beneath:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_cc_Additional_Information_Answers_INS 
ON cc_Additional_Information_Answers
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE temp_answers 
    (
         TempAnswer VARCHAR(50), 
         TempAdditional_Information_ItemID INT
    )

    INSERT INTO temp_answers (TempAnswer, TempAdditional_Information_ItemID) 
        SELECT Description, Additional_Information_ItemID 
        FROM inserted

    DECLARE @Answer varchar(50)
    SELECT @Answer = '''%' + t.TempAnswer + '%''' FROM temp_answers t

    DECLARE @ItemId int
    SELECT @ItemId = t.TempAdditional_Information_ItemID FROM temp_answers t

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
              FROM cc_Additional_Information_Answers a 
              WHERE a.Description LIKE @Answer 
               AND a.Additional_Information_ItemID = @ItemId)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Answer is too similar to pre-existing answers for this item', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RETURN
    END

    DROP TABLE temp_answers
END 
GO
```

And this is my insert query:

```
INSERT INTO cc_Additional_Information_Answers (Additional_Information_ItemID, Description)
VALUES (103, 'a')
```

And the pre-existing record:

[image: existing record]

Thanks in advance, SQL community!

**EDIT:** this also does not behave as expected. . .

```
INSERT INTO cc_Additional_Information_Answers (Additional_Information_ItemID, Description)
VALUES (103, 'a')
```

Given this data

[image]

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR logical flaw. It assumes there will only ever be a single row in the inserted table. This is not how triggers work in sql server, they fire once per operation. Also, using persistent tables as temp tables is very problematic. You have created a race condition here that is not needed. Simply join to inserted any time you need it throughout your trigger.

Comment: I would also be very cautious of issuing a rollback in a trigger. If your calling code has a transaction it will likely crash because the transaction won't be available anymore to rollback from the application.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for your feedback; I’ll work in your suggestions. I don’t see how they’ll solve the issue I’ve described though.

Comment: @SeanLange I can say with certainty that only one record will be inserted per transaction. We are not doing batch inserts

Comment: The answer could be  '%' + t.TempAnswer + '%' FROM temp_answers t
(without the extra quotes)…

Comment: If exactly one row will be inserted in any given transaction then you should check the `count()` of `inserted` and `RaIsError` or `throw` if the count is not `1`. You probably don't mean to be forcing quotes into the pattern, but that is what the extra quotes in `'''%' + t.TempAnswer + '%'''` are doing: it will only match a string beginning and ending with a `'`.

Comment: Just to confirm: I need to run my query with something like `’%a%’`; I need to make sure what is getting inserted is not in anyway similar to what may already be there

Comment: Try `declare @P as VarChar(10) = '%foo%'; select case when 'foot' like @P then 1 else 0 end;` and `declare @P as VarChar(10) = '''%foo%'''; select case when 'foot' like @P then 1 else 0 end;`. Which do you want?

Comment: Don't assume there will only ever be a single row. It will come back to bite you. That may be how it works right now but maybe not in the future. And there are always those times where you manually add data because of some glitch. Far better to just write your trigger correctly and not have to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Your IF EXISTS will always evaluate to true because the inserted value is already inserted (although it can be rolled back) when the trigger runs (it's an "AFTER" trigger).
So you will want to inspect only those records that existed in the table before the insertion. I always use an outer join for this. Also: I would never create a table in a trigger. The following should work as expected:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_cc_Additional_Information_Answers_INS ON cc_Additional_Information_Answers
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN

  IF EXISTS(
     SELECT 1 FROM cc_Additional_Information_Answers a 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN inserted i ON a.Additional_Information_AnswerID = i.Additional_Information_AnswerID
       INNER JOIN inserted temp ON a.Additional_Information_ItemID = temp.Additional_Information_ItemID
      WHERE a.Description LIKE '%' + temp.Description + '%'
        AND i.Additional_Information_AnswerID IS NULL
     )
     BEGIN
       RAISERROR('Answer is too similar to pre-existing answers for this item', 16, 1)
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
       RETURN
     END
END 
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. With the outer join, is the logic to check for answerID = null due to the fact that the answer ID will be inserted by the DB after the insert query has run?

Comment: @SteveBoniface Yes, the intention of outer join and "is null" is to make sure to only compare to those records that are not currently being inserted.

Comment: I think this is precisely what I need. Will give it a shot and will confirm. Thank you!

Comment: I don’t understand why Rollback transaction works if the insert has already been executed though. That part doesn’t make sense to me. Doesn’t the insert have to be committed to the DB to get an identity value assigned to that record?

Comment: @SteveBoniface From outside the transaction, this would be considered a "dirty read", but from inside, we of course must be able to see our own changes. And for the ID... yes, that's where "gaps" in the identity columns can come from.

Comment: Oh okay. That makes more sense. So the inserted record doesn’t become committed until it has cleared what may be going on in an insert trigger?

Comment: @SteveBoniface Correct, the insert is comitted only if the trigger runs through without error or rollback.